# Oracle: Inner Row Source of Nested Loop - Incorrect Estimated Rows?

Tags: oracle, nested-loops, sql-execution-plan, rowid, cardinality-estimation

My understanding is that the estimated number of rows in an explain plan for the inner row source of a nested loop join reflects the number of rows for just one iteration of that nested loop.

In the following example, step 6 of the explain plan is an inner row source of a nested loop join that is obtaining a row by one ROWID at a time.  Therefore, it ought to have an estimated rows of 1 (there is only 1 row per ROWID).

Why is step 6's `table access by index ROWID` showing 100 (I expected it to show 1)?

Using Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition.

```sql
drop table "C";
drop table "P";

create table "P"
  ( p_id  NUMBER
  , p_num NUMBER
  , p_pad CHAR(200 byte)
  )
;

insert
  into "P" (p_id, p_num, p_pad)
  select level
       , mod(level-1,200/2)
       , ' '
    from dual
    connect by level <= 200
;

create table "C"
  ( c_id  NUMBER
  , p_id  NUMBER
  , c_pad CHAR(200 byte)
  )
;

insert /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel (auto) */
  into "C" (c_id, p_id, c_pad)
  with
    "D" as
    ( select /*+ materialize */ null from dual connect by level <= 100
    )
    select rownum      c_id
         , p_id        p_id
         , ' '         c_pad
      from "P", "D"
;
commit;
```

```sql
create index IX_P on p (p_num);   
create unique index IU_P on p (p_id);
alter table p add constraint UK_P unique (p_id) rely using index IU_P enable validate;
alter table C add constraint R_C foreign key (p_id) references p (p_id) rely enable validate;
create index IR_C on _C (p_id);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OwnName => null, TabName => 'P', cascade => true);
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(OwnName => null, TabName => 'C', cascade => true);
```

```sql
select /*+ optimizer_features_enable('19.1.0')
           use_nl (P C) */
       *
  from "P"
       join "C"
         on P.p_id = C.p_id
            and P.p_num = 1
;
plan hash value: 3840235794

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | Operation                             | name | rows  | Bytes | cost (%CPU)| time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | select statement                      |      |   200 | 83000 |   205   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  nested LOOPS                         |      |   200 | 83000 |   205   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   nested LOOPS                        |      |   200 | 83000 |   205   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    table access by index ROWID BATCHED| P    |     2 |   414 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     index range scan                  | IX_P |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    index range scan                   | IR_C |   100 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |   table access by index ROWID         | C    |   100 | 20800 |   101   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("P"."P_NUM"=1)
   5 - access("P"."P_ID"="C"."P_ID")
```

Outer row source step 3 multiplied by Inner row source step 5 = Nested Loop step 2.

However, Outer row source step 2 multiplied by Inner row source step 6 <> Nested Loop step 1.

I agree the total of step 1 ought to be 200, but don't understand why step 6 has an estimated rows of 100.

Why does step 6 have an estimated rows of 100 instead of 1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can see what row counts will be expected in the outer `NESTED LOOP`

```
select p_id, count(*) from C where p_id in (
select p_id from P where p_num = 1)
group by p_id;

      P_ID   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
         2        100
       102        100
```

So realy each iteration expects to get 100 rows.

If you run the query with the hint `gather_plan_statistics` you can see the  number of `Starts` and the total actual rows `A-Rows`.

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics use_nl (P C) */
       *
  from "P"
       join "C"
         on P.p_id = C.p_id
            and P.p_num = 1

SQL_ID  927pggk6scpwt, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics use_nl (P C) */        *   from "P"   
     join "C"          on P.p_id = C.p_id             and P.p_num = 1
 
Plan hash value: 2326820011
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |      |      1 |        |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     213 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                         |      |      1 |    200 |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     213 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                        |      |      1 |    200 |    200 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| P    |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IX_P |      1 |      2 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IR_C |      2 |    100 |    200 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | C    |    200 |    100 |    200 |00:00:00.01 |     200 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   4 - access("P"."P_NUM"=1)
   5 - access("P"."P_ID"="C"."P_ID")
```

I.e. the operation 5 was *started* two times (column `Starts`) with a *total* of 200 rows (column `A-Rows`)

Operation 6 was started 200 times each time to get *one* row.

Comment: Thanks.  My understanding is ``Starts`` multiplied by ``E-Rows`` = ``A-Rows``.  However, this is not true for operation 6.  The question remains, why is ``E-Rows`` not equal to 1 for operation 6?

Comment: I completely agree@AlexBartsmon , but you'll have to ask the Oracle designers. Most probably they saw it pretty obvious to post the information that you get always one row with the rowid access so they made an exception here and show the total...

Answer (score 0):

I think [this Oracle documentation paragraph](https://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sql/joins/nested-loops.html) explains this scenario fairly well:

> Multiple nested loops operations can occasionally show up in the execution plan for just one join, which indicates that Oracle used the nested-loop batching optimization technique. What this method does is transform a single join of two row sources into a join of the driving row source to one copy of the probe row source that is joined to a replica of itself on ROWID; since we now have three row sources, we need at least two nested loops. The probe row source copy that is used to perform a self join on ROWID is used to filter rows, so it will have a corresponding `TABLE ACCESS BY ... ROWID` entry in the execution plan. This cost-based optimization can often reduce I/O although the execution plan may not transparently display the benefits.

Step 6 in your example is the "probe row source copy"; it's basically a cached version of table C, so it has 100 rows. But its cost is shared among all of the outer nested loops - the table was only accessed once - so it's already included in the total from step 2. (I think?)